# Should I rinse my equipment after sanitizing with Star San HB Five Star?

Tags: sanitation, starsan

I want to begin my first batch but I know sanitizing is really important and I don't want to make mistake about it, so I read *How to brew - Everything you need to know to brew great beer every time* and it is written about sanitizing with Star San:

> No-rinse. Can be used via immersion or spraying. Will sanitize clean surfaces with 30 sec. contact time.

So, I went on [Brouwland](https://www.brouwland.com/en/our-products/cleaning/cleaning-products/d/star-san-hb-five-star-118-ml-en-it) to make my order and I saw about the product:

> Prepare a solution of 15 - 25 ml Star San HB™ per 10 L of water. Apply on surface with a cloth, mop, sponge, spray or by immersion. Spray 15-20 cm from surface and rub with a brush, cloth or sponge. The surface must remain wet for **at least 1 minute. Rinse with water of the same temperature.**

There are differences about time and rince. About the time, I guess it is not really important and I can wait 60 seconds without risks. But about rince: **should I do it or not?**

To finish and add some confusion, Five Star edits a [cleaning guide](https://www.brouwland.com/content/docs/FIVE_STAR_cleaning_guide_11_talen_118x118_lowres.pdf) who says:

> Your equipment is ready for use immediately after removing the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No rinse needed, if you follow the description on the bottle for the proper mix. If I remember correctly, the sanitization compound gets deactivated at a pH that's normal for brewing.

There is a nice podcast with the inventor of starsan, where he explains that even the 30 secs are not needed. I'll post a link for you.

Comment: There are two podcast with guys from starsan: http://podbay.fm/show/75092679/e/1175200200?autostart=1 and http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/post1827/

Comment: Yep star-san is a no rinse sanitizer. Let as much drain out as possible, some foam will have no ill effects on your brew. You can even reuse starsan, just check the pH if it's still below 3.0 Its good to go. You should NOT rinse it, the rinse can introduce infections.